# How can I sort a ListBox using only XAML and no code-behind?

Tags: wpf, xaml, sorting, mvvm, listbox

I need to sort the strings in a `ListBox`, but it is bound to the view model by another component via the `DataContext`. So I can't directly instantiate the view model in XAML, as in [this example](http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007081301.aspx), which uses the `ObjectDataProvider`.

In my XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfStrings}" />
```

In my view model:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> CollectionOfStrings
{
    get { return collectionOfStrings; }
}
```

In another component:

```
view.DataContext = new ViewModel();
```

There is no code behind! So using purely XAML, how would I sort the items in the ListBox? Again, the XAML doesn't own the instantiation of the view model.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Use a [`CollectionViewSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx):

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedItems" Source="{Binding CollectionOfStrings}"
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=Win‌​dowsBase">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="SomePropertyOnYourItems"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedItems}}"/>
```

You might want to wrap your strings in a custom VM class so you can more easily apply sorting behavior.

Comment: Thanks, Kent! Binding the Source attribute on a CollectionViewSource was the missing link for me. I appreciate it. In this case, I didn't want a custom VM class, so I just left off the PropertyName attribute, which apparently works for string collections just fine.

Comment: Also, to any onlookers out there, the SortDescription tag takes a Direction attribute.

Comment: What if the ListBox is a part of a DataTemplate representing a property of a object that is a list of items. Can't I do the sorting inside the ListBox somehow?

Comment: Can you tell us where the smc namespace looks like. I'm not succesfully finding SortDescription using Xaml.

Comment: Comment by [franssu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/414314/franssu): `scm` includes the "System.ComponentModel" namespace from the WindowsBase assembly. `(xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase")`

Comment: for Silverlight xmlns:scm="="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=System.Windows"

Comment: There seems to be some hidden characters in the code snippet. Copying it to notepad++ shows this for example 'Win??dowsBase'
I had the SortOnDescription issue also. The characters don't show up in blend. Retyping 'WindowsBase' fixed it for me. I would edit the snippet but it complains that I need to edit more than 6 characters.

Answer (score 0):

If attached property qualifies as no code the following can be used:

```
public static class Sort
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DirectionProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Direction",
        typeof(ListSortDirection?),
        typeof(Sort),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            default(ListSortDirection?),
            OnDirectionChanged));

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(ItemsControl))]
    public static ListSortDirection? GetDirection(ItemsControl element)
    {
        return (ListSortDirection)element.GetValue(DirectionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDirection(ItemsControl element, ListSortDirection? value)
    {
        element.SetValue(DirectionProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnDirectionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is ItemsControl { Items: { } items })
        {
            if (e.NewValue is ListSortDirection direction)
            {
                items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(string.Empty, direction));
            }
            else if (e.OldValue is ListSortDirection old &&
                     items.SortDescriptions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Direction == old) is { } oldDescription)
            {
                items.SortDescriptions.Remove(oldDescription);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in xaml:

```
<ListBox local:Sort.Direction="Ascending"
         ... />
```

Another attached property that is of type `SortDescription`  probably makes sense in many cases.