# Sort List with Databinding Windows Universal C#

Tags: c#, windows, list, xaml, universal

I get a list by sending a httprequest and retrieving text in json format. I created this List:

```
<ListBox Background="Red" ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="Itemlist">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"></TextBlock>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding InventoryItem.properties.name}" Foreground="Green"></TextBlock>
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now I want to sort this list. The Listitems with the highest ammount of price should be first. How do i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I sort a ListBox using only XAML and no code-behind?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280704/how-can-i-sort-a-listbox-using-only-xaml-and-no-code-behind)

Comment: @Aron No, i checked this already out, im interested in how to order a list in c#.

Comment: you can sort the list. However that will do nothing to your UI, depending when you sort the list.

Comment: It does, because i bind to null and then i rebind it to my list. So how do i sort this ? @Aron

Comment: I would advise against doing precisely that, since it will cause the whole ListBox to rebind, which will mean you would lose all UI state, and the UI would have to regenerate all the UI elements. However if you must do so, you do `Foo = Foo.OrderBy(x => x.Price).ToList();`. However it would STILL not work, unless you wire up your property as a INPC property.

Comment: var test =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Jsonformat.RootObject>(content);
            var orderedlist =  test.Items.OrderBy(Price => test.Price);
            
            Itemlist.DataContext = orderedlist; 
            Didnt work :U @Aron whats an inpc property, i didnt find a good page which explains it

Comment: OMG you are directly attaching it to the `UIElement.DataContext`? Also, you obviously didn't read what I posted correctly. What happened to the `.ToList()`?

Comment: @Aron Whats wrong with that i could also Bind it directly in Xaml and my options are limited, im developing for windows universal^^ I see i forgot .ToList(); i readdet it. Would it be better to add the .sort(); for my complex list?

Comment: @Aron I edited it with ".ToList()" but the list doesnt get sorted in any way its still the same order

Comment: I dont bind it to datacontext i bind it to itemsource @Aron

Comment: Ahem `Itemlist.DataContext = orderedlist;` Why do you refuse to bind the ItemList to a `CollectionViewSource` and have that sort the list? Under the covers that is exactly what is already happening.

Comment: @Ahem I try it but in windows universal there is no "CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions"

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527686/A-WinRT-CollectionView-class-with-Filtering-and-So

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I call the .sort() function on the list:

```
  test.Items.Sort();

 public class Item:IComparable<Item>
    {
        public InventoryItem InventoryItem { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Item other)
        {
            return this.Price.CompareTo(other.Price);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new kind of list inheriting from ObservableCollection :

```
public class MyItemsList:ObservableCollection<Item>
{
}
```

Once you have done that, you can order the list following the pattern @matthias Herrmann has shown you.

```
MyItemsListInstance.Items.Sort();

 public class Item:IComparable<Item>
    {
        public InventoryItem InventoryItem { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Item other)
        {
            return this.Price.CompareTo(other.Price);
        }
```

Given that you implemented the List as ObservableCollection now any change over the **list structure** will raise notifications to automatically refresh the View (UI).

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are binding the ItemList ListBox to a *property*? (named ItemList in example)

In the getter of the property, you can add a custom transform to sort the data passed through from the source list object.

Eg.

```
private List<Item> itemList = ///etc.

public List<Item> ItemList //binding to this
{
    public get { return itemList.OrderByDescending(x => x.price).ToList(); }
}
```

Comment: -1 This is such a incredibly bad piece of code, I don't know where to start. `OrderByDescending` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` not `List<T>`. This would force the list to be sorted each time you load the display. It does not listen to new objects being added to the list...I could go ON and ON.

Comment: It's meant as an example of how to do a transform in a getter, sure, you'd want to be using something IObservable anyway rather than a simple list, but as a basic example it works. OP needs to apply the concept to however they have done their code behind. 

But yes, I do take your point, this was a poor answer.

Comment: Anything but the most basic transforms or possibly cached transforms in the getter will produce unexpected results. Here you have a lazy evaluated transform which takes a non-trivial amount of resources to complete.

Comment: @Aron Can you help me?