# Can I setup a CollectionViewSource for a XAML non-bound ListBox sort?

Tags: wpf, xaml, sorting, listbox

I referenced this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280704/how-can-i-sort-a-listbox-using-only-xaml-and-no-code-behind) but don't understand how the < CollectionViewSource > is supposed to be setup.  I am working with this very simple ListBox:

```
  <Window xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase" ...

  <ListBox>
    <CollectionViewSource>
      <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Content" Direction="Ascending" />
      </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
    <ListBoxItem>ctext1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>btext2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>atext3</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>dtext4</ListBoxItem>
  </ListBox>
```

This treats the < CollectionViewSource > element as another item in the ListBox collection.  I assume this is because  < CollectionViewSource > is not setup properly, but since I'm just learning this, perhaps I have a basic misunderstanding.  I understand the sort would normally be done in code behind along with a view model, but I'm just trying to understand how the sort is accessed in pure XAML.

1) Is it possible to setup the sort for this simple ListBox implementation?

2) What is required?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the CVS as resource, and reference to it.
https://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html
Look under: How to create a CollectionView in XAML

Comment: That wasn't what I was looking for, but it was a great link. Thanks.  For now I had to do this:  `ListBox1.Items.Add("ctext3")       ListBox1.Items.Add("atext1") ListBox1.Items.Add("dtext4")       ListBox1.Items.Add("btext2") ListBox1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(New SortDescription With {.Direction = ListSortDirection.Descending})`.  I was really looking for a way to that in XAML only.